# Why is paho-mqtt ignoring my subscription

Tags: python-3.x, mqtt, paho

I am using the following code

```
    client.loop_start()
    client.subscribe("indentify/+")
    client.subscribe("indentify/#")
    client.subscribe("status/#")
    #client.subscribe("#")
    client.on_message=on_message
```

When I send identify/xxx to the server it is ignored.  If I uncomment the last subscribe line I see the messages and everything else which is to be expected.
A Perl script doing essentially the same thing sees the messages as expected.

Running paho_mqtt-1.5.1-py3-none-any.whl and Python 3.8.10
On a Ubuntu 20.04.3 server.
Any ideas would be appreciated.
Jim.

Comment: Edit the question to show more of the code, but setting the `on_message` callback before subscribing is good practice. Also not calling subscribe before the connection has completed (e.g. in the `on_connect` callback)

Comment: Close due to spelling mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not ignoring your subscription, it's doing exactly what you asked of it. As per a large number of computer problems, what you asked it to do is not what you *wanted* it to do.

Let's have a closer look:

```
              v
              |
Subscribe to indentify/+
Subscribe to indentify/#
Publish   to identify/xxx
              |
              ^
```

Can you see the problem *now?* I certainly *hope* so.

I suspect your "essentially the same" Perl script may have better spelling than your Python code. "Indentify" sounds like something Python coders do to fix indentation issues :-)

---

And, in case my answer has been lost in the rambling that is often my nature, here's the Janet and John bit:

> You did not spell "identify" correctly when subscribing. There's an extraneous "n" between the first two characters ("i" and "d"), giving you "i ***n*** dentify" (sans spaces - they're just there to make it *more* obvious).